# rearranging a string structure in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, for-loop, data-structures

I am cleaning multiple pdf files. And I have combined two dictionaries to get three outputs. 
The **file name** which is key, the word **index** and the word **count**.

```
for key, value in countDict.items():
    for word, count in value.items():
        for token, index in vocabDict.items():
                if word==token:
                    print(key,index,count)
```

The three outputs are printed as a string

```
PP3188 2498 1
PP3188 1834 10
PP3188 2063 1
PP3278 447 1
PP3278 1458 1
PP3160 2433 5
PP3160 1889 2
```

Is there a way to group this output to make it look like this:

```
PP3188, 2498 : 1, 1834 : 10, 2063 :1
PP3278, 447 : 1, 1458 : 1
PP3160, 2433 : 5, 1889 : 2
```

Any idea how to achieve this structure? or a similar output?
thank you.

Comment: What do the original dictionaries look like?

Comment: the answer is yes. Maybe add a demo data dictionary  to your question so we can show you how. You did not even try to group, where is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the structure you want is probably defaultdict of dicts. I'll show you.

```
{
    'PP3188': {
        2498: 1,
        1834: 10,
        2063: 1
    },
    'PP3278': {
        447: 1,
        1458:1
    },
    'PP3160': {
        2433: 5,
        1889: 2
    }
}
```

Here is the sample code.

```
from collections import defaultdict

... some code ...

data = defaultdict(dict)

for key, value in countDict.items():
    for word, count in value.items():
        for token, index in vocabDict.items():
                if word==token:
                    data[key][index] = count
```

The difference between mine and @Epion's answer is that in his answer, you have dict with key as the `PPxxxx` and value is list of the tuples and mine is dict with values of dicts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could have a `defaultdict(list)` structure that holds `key` as its keys, and value being a list of tuples `(index, count)`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

our_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

Then, instead of printing you would be performing an append:

```
for key, value in countDict.items():
    for word, count in value.items():
        for token, index in vocabDict.items():
                if word==token:
                    our_dict[key].append((index, count))
```

With such a structure you could print all the contents afterwards:

```
for key, values_list in our_dict.items():
    for (index, count) in values_list:
        print(key, index, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

With minimum modifications to your code this could be accomplished as

```
for key, value in countDict.items():
    entries = [key]
    for word, count in value.items():
        for token, index in vocabDict.items():
                if word==token:
                    entries.append(str(index) + " : " + str(count))
                    print(key,index,count)

    print(", ".join(entries))
```